# Counting one pair poker hands (five cards per hand)

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

I understand how to find the number of one-pair poker hands there are, but I am being asked to explain how the following logic is incorrect:

Choose any card ($52$ ways), then choose another card of the same value to make the pair ($3$ ways), then choose three more cards of different values ($48$ ways, $44$ ways, $40$ ways). The answer is $52 \cdot 3 \cdot 48 \cdot 44 \cdot 40 = 13'178'880$.

I can't quite figure out how to explain why this is wrong besides the order of cards drawn doesn't matter. I also need to explain why the wrong answer is a multiple of the right answer ($1'098'240$).

Comment: Because the wrong answer is 12 times the correct answer, it means that the "incorrect logic" counted 12 times the same hand. Can you see why?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're right that the order doesn't matter, and in this case the fact that the "incorrect" solution considered the order means that they overcounted the total number of hands by a factor of 12.

Here's how you would find the correct answer: to get the pair, pick one out of 13 values and then choose two cards out of the four potential cards of that value to get the pair. Now pick any three other values, and choose any of the four potential cards for each of those. This gives a final solution of

$$ {13 \choose 1}{4 \choose 2} {12 \choose 3}\cdot 4^3 = 1098240.$$

The incorrect solution is wrong because they overcounted in several ways: first because the order of the initial pair doesn't matter (for example, choosing a 4 of hearts and then picking the 4 of spades is counted separately from choosing the 4 of spades and then the 4 of hearts) and then because they again considered the order of the next set of cards.

This wrong solution is actually counting the number of ways to draw a one-pair poker hand from a deck, considering order and assuming that the pair is drawn first. There are $2! = 2$ ways to arrange the pair and $3! = 6$ ways to arrange the other three cards in a hand drawn this way, and each of these arrangements is counted as a distinct hand using this method. So the incorrect solution overcounts by a factor of $2!\cdot 3! = 12$.

Answer (score 3):

You are right. The order of the cards drawn does not matter. The answer is wrong because of double counting.

Now the given wrong answer ($13,178,880$) is $12$ times the correct answer ($1,098,240$). Here's why.

The two cards of the same rank can be ordered in $2$ ways and the three of different ranks in $3! = 6$ ways. Taking both into account, the same hand is counted $2 \times 6 = 12$ times.